# How to add custom links in views showing taxonomy in drupal

Tags: php, html, css, drupal

I had created a view where it shows taxonomy. Now i want to put a href tag before the taxonomy name by programatically . What i have done is this

```
<?php
// $Id$

/**
 * @file
 * Museum
 */
function museum_views_pre_render(&$view) {
    if ($view->name == 'museumlist')
    {
     //var_dump($view);
     foreach ($view->result as $result) {
            $childern=taxonomy_get_children($result->tid);
         //var_dump($result);
      // Replace all empty fields with the dash '-' character.
     $result->taxonomy_term_data_name='<a href="google.com">'.$result->taxonomy_term_data_name.'</a>';
}
    }
}
```

So for example i want to link the taxonomy_term_data_name to google.com for example if it has no children. 
How to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

I would go for this from view's template file. In Advanced / Theme information check which view template you have to change and even get it's default content there.